# Node.JS - I need to call REST API endpoint in infinite loop in my app

Tags: node.js, loops, websocket, chat

I have Node.JS server application which communicates with more clients via Web Sockets. Now I need to extend my solution in this way: Every time when a client connects to the server and obtains a unique ID so from this point it is necessary to constantly call one special REST API endpoint (in some kind of infinite loop) with obtained client ID as a parameter and process changes comming from the REST API's response.

Example:
- Client 1 connects to the server. Web socket is opened and communication is opened. At this point the infinite loop starts and REST endpoint (e.g. /info?clientId=Client1) is called again and again...

- after 5 minutes Client 2 also connects to the server and REST endpoint starts to be called again and again (/info/clientId=Client2).
- suddenly /info?clientId=Client1 returns changed data and now it is a time to react. I will send some special response to opened web socket but infinite loop should still run for both Client 1 and Client 2.

This should be same for all clients (also new connected clients at a time when some other clients are being served).

I do not know how should I implement this loop... I tried to google it but maybe if you could give me some advice or recommend me some articles it would be very helpful for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical endless loop polling some endpoint in node.js will involve a `setTimeout()` invoked in the completion handler from the previous call.  So, since you provided no real code, here's an outline of how it would work:

```
function makeCall(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    request(...., function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
           // error handling here
        } else {
           // process data here
           // start next API call after some timeout
           setTimeout(function() {
               makeCall(arg1, arg2, arg3);
           }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If I understand this in a correct way so I will call some function "request" with client ID as a parameter (instead of yours ....) and return some API response and then I process it in else { // process data here ?

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood - there are lots of ways you could make your API call, but I've shown it using the `request()` function in this module: https://github.com/request/request.  The arguments to `request()` are explained there.

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood did you look at my answer? I don't think setTimeout helps you at all.

Comment: @JasonLivesay - There are very few real world cases where you literally want to pound an API as fast as possible.  Once you get a few clients doing that at once, it quickly ruins the scalability of your server - thus you usually make an API call, then wait some period of time before making the next one.  That's the point of the `setTimeout()`.  Why the downvote?  The more scalable way to do this would not involve polling an API at all, but using a webSocket and letting the server just push new info to the client when needed.

Comment: Making the request was really only a small part of his problem, and he presented as if the request might not reply immediately.

Comment: @JasonLivesay - Well, he seemed to me to be asking how to make the next request after the first one endlessly so that's what I answered and this seemed to be the solution the OP was looking for (as judged by the accepted answer).  You made a more complicated answer.  It's up to the OP if that is more what they want or not.  My answer doesn't matter how long the request takes to reply.  He can set the `setTimeout()` to whatever time is appropriate for the use case.  Still not sure why you downvoted an answer that is simple, works and is what the OP seemed to want.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers... it gave me the way. I have a problem now that I need to pass 3 parameters to my "makeCall" function. But don't know how because makeCall in setTimeout is reference...

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood - I updated my answer to show `makeCall()` with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like polling or long-polling.  I would put that in a separate module and raise an event on new data.

I didn't test this code so you may need to fix some things but it is the general idea.

```
// in poll.js                                    
var events = require('events');                  
var request = require('request');                

function Checker(url) {                          
  var self = this;                               

  function resp(e,r,body) {                      
    if (body.indexOf('new data'===0)) {          
      self.emit('newdata', {data:body.substr(10)});                                                  
    }                                            
    setTimeout(function(){self.check(url, resp);}, 1000);                       
  }                                              

  this.url = url;                                

  this.check = function(url) {                   
    request.get(url, resp);                      
  }                                              

  this.check(url);      

}                                                

Checker.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;


module.exports = Checker;                        

// in server.js                                  
var Checker = require('./poll.js');              
io.on('connection', function (socket) {          
  var checker = new Checker('http://theurl.com/'+socket.id);                                          
  checker.on('newdata', function(data) {         
     socket.emit('newdata', data );                 
  });                                            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the endpoint using axios and `setInterval()` function .
Note: to ensure the previous request has been processed completely, you may use the flag

Eg :

```
let flag=true;

setInterval(()=>{
if(flag==true)
    axios.post(endpointUrl,reqBody);
},timeout)


const endpointName=async (req,res)=>{
//do something with req body and send response.
//make flag false till your processing get complete
//as soon as it gets complete and you want to get the endpoint called again make the flag true.
}
```